# The probability of comparing two stopping times in simple random walk

Tags: random-walk, stopping-times

For a simple random walk $\{X_n\}$ starting at point zero, let $T_k=\inf\{n>0|X_n=k\}$.
What's probability that $P\{T_k<T_0|X_0=0\}$ for $k\ne 0$?

Note that $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i$ where $P\{\xi_i=1\}=p$, $P\{\xi_i=-1\}=1-p$ and $\{\xi_i\}$ is i.i.d. sequence.

Comment: What's $y$ exactly?

Comment: Do you mean $n>0$ or $n\geq1$ in the definition of $T_k$? Seeing as how you start with $X_0=0$ and not $X_1=0$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for your questions. I have corrected my notation to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: You should start the sum at $i=1$. Otherwise $\{X_0=0\}$ has probability zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean $T_y =\inf\{n>0 : X_n = y\}$ and $p = P( X_1 = 1 | X_0 = 0)$. For $y = 1$ we have by distinguishing the first step $P( T_y < T_0 | X_0 = 0) = P( X_1 = 1 | X_0 = 0) = p$. ($y = -1$ is analogue, such that  $P( T_y < T_0 | X_0 = 0) = 1 - p$)

Define $T^E_y =\inf\{n\ge 0 : X_n = y\}$

Let $y > 1 $ and $f(z) := P( T^E_y < T^E_0 | X_0 = z)$ for $z \in \{0 , \ldots , y\}$. Again by the first step argument
$$P( T_y < T_0 | X_0 = 0) = P( X_1 = 1 | X_0 = 0) P( T^E_y < T^E_0 | X_1 = 1) = p \cdot f(1)$$
Thus we are interested in $f(1)$.
Again by first step argument we get the recursion formula
$$f(z) = p f(z+1) + (1-p) f(z-1)$$
for $z \in \{1 , \ldots , y-1\}$ and we know that obviously $f(0) = 0$ and $f(y) =1$. The formula above yields that
$f(z+1) - f(z) = \frac{1-p}p (f(z) - f(z-1)) = \left( \frac{1-p}p\right)^z f(1)$.
Thus for $z= y-1$:
$$1= f(y) = \sum_{z=0}^{y-1} f(z+1) - f(z) = f(1) \sum_{z=0}^{y-1} \left( \frac{1-p}p\right)^z = \begin{cases}  f(1) \frac{1 - (\frac{1-p}{p})^y}{1 - \frac{1-p}{p}} &: p\neq \frac 1 2 \\ f(1) y &: \text{else}\end{cases}$$
Therefore
$$f(1) = \begin{cases} \frac{2p-1}{p(1 - (\frac{1-p}{p})^y)} &: p\neq \frac 1 2\\ \frac 1 y &: \text{else} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for your warm hearted help! I think your answer is right and the proof can be applied similarly when $y<1$.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I forgot to write that $y<1$ is analogue.

Comment: @Falrach How can I show that $P(T_k < \infty)=1$.

Comment: Assuming that we condition on $X_0 = \ell$ and $k > \ell > m$, then $\mathbb P (T_k < T_m \vert X_0 = \ell) = f(z)$ with $z=\ell-m$ and $y= k-m$. By the formulas above you can compute $f(z)$. Then by letting $m\to\infty$ you may see that $f(z) \to 1$.